# GreenAddress: Noticfication of receiving transaction

Tags: blockchain, python, green-address, pycoin

I'm developing python project using `greenaddress` API. I use `pycoin` package.
I almost completed, but I can't resolve notification problem.
Using `greenaddress` API, the notification received is as follow.

```
{'wallet_id': '139183', 'txhash':    '0fd5cdf75d8a9979b454b36ba8dc36917dfc5b3726622f5291a24f0dcd4ab27f',    'subaccounts': [37], 'value': '-207'}
```

I want to get raw tx from this information, but I can't.
Can I get raw tx from this information by using `pycoin` and `greenaddress` API?
Pls, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `pycoin` and `greenadderss` you can't `getrawtransaction`.

using bitcoin-core you can getrawtrasnaction as hex or encoded.

```
bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction "mytxid" true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will refer to it. I have a question. Using pycoin, is it difficult to implement greenaddress api?

Comment: I don't have any experiments with greenaddress, But AFAICT blockchain.info is fully compatible with pycoin and i'm pretty sure that you can get rawtransaction from blockchain.